# java.util.List can not assign classes with List.of

Tags: java, list

My code has an error that says

```
"The method of (Main.person, Main.person, Main.person, Main.person, Main.person) is undefined for the type List"
```

I know that means I can't create the objects (which are Persons in my case) but I really couldn't find the mistake.

The error message appear at "List.of()" below the main method.

```
package imparative;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static imparative.Main.Gender.*;

public class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
          List<Person> people = List.of(
               new Person("John", MALE),
               new Person("Maria", FEMALE),
               new Person("Aisha", FEMALE),
               new Person("Alex", MALE),
               new Person("Alice", FEMALE)
          );
      
          // imperative approach
          List<Person> females = new ArrayList<>();
           
          for (Person person : people) {
               if (FEMALE.equals(person.gender)) {
                    females.add(person);;
               }
          }
      
          for (Person female : females) {
               System.out.println(female);
          }
     }
  
     // Define and object named Person.
     static class Person {
          // Define Object attributes which are name and gender.
          private final String name;
          private final Gender gender;
         
          // Constructor (a special method that is used to initialize an object).
          // Constructor will be called when an object of a class is created.
          Person(String name, Gender gender) {
               this.name = name;
               this.gender = gender;;
          }
         
          // overrides method in the superclass
          @Override
          public String toString() {
               return "Person{" + "name='" + name + '\'' + ", gender=" + gender + '}';
          }
     }
        
     // create a var named Gender and put some values
     enum Gender {
          MALE, FEMALE
     }
}
```

Comment: compiles fine for me

Comment: The method List.of exists since Java 9. Please check your settings.

Comment: i've checked my java version and i realized my java version is 8. currently downloading the java 9 and gonna install it. Thanks for the help :D . java 9 is quite new that i didnt notice it exist.

Comment: Stack Overflow welcomes posting your own Answer to your own Question. I suggest you do so. Then you can accept that Answer, marking the page as resolved.

Comment: Lesson learned: First step in debugging is to study carefully the Javadoc for the class and method.

Comment: @BasilBourque I am not sure if in this case it is not better to just close the question ".. typo"

Comment: @dreamcrash Well the cause is not a typo. The cause came from a serious technical problem: Using the wrong version of Java. I imagine this is a common problem, as the `List.of`/`Set.of` methods would not be obvious as newly added to Java. So a resolved question-answer here could be good for posterity.

Comment: i will accept the answer but unfortunately the issue is still there after i installed java 9 :(

Comment: i installed java 9, change JAVA_HOME path to the jdk 9 directory, enable java 9 SE in the java config app, and set java home path in atom to jdk 9 directory. but the problem still exist :(

Comment: @UnbAnx You must also configure your project in your [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) to specify Java 9 rather than 8 for both compiling and executing. This is not simple, as the IDEs tend to have these setting spread out over various dialogs and settings — quite annoying. Search Stack Overflow to learn how in your particular IDE. If using Maven, Gradle, etc to configure your project, you’ll need edits there too.

Comment: Instead of List.of() you can also use Arrays.asList(). This method exists in Java 8.

Comment: @BasilBourque Yep you are right, I will retract my vote

Comment: @BasilBourque how do i specify java 9 in my project?. as i've said i have changed java home path in my IDE to jdk 9 directory but how do specify it in my project?. or i might have to remove the java 8 first? is it okay? will it leads to any problem?

Comment: But beware that `Arrays.asList` has very different behavior, with write-through to the backing array.

Comment: btw thanks for all the response guys, didnt know the community is very responsive :)

Comment: You can leave multiple versions of Java installed, not a problem, commonly done by developers/testers. As I said, you’ll need to search for help with your particular IDE, and with Maven/Gradle/Ivy/etc. Configurations vary by IDE, and by version of IDE. As I said, quite annoying but an uncomfortable chore we all must learn and perform. If keeping up with the 6-month releases of Java, we must perform quite often. I wish the IDEs added a “Wizard” tool to perform the chore for us.

Comment: @BasilBourque ok im gonna take a look at that. btw i used Maven to generate the project

Comment: ok it works after i created a new project and copid the source code into the new project. Thx for the help everyone :)  .

Answer (score 0):

I need to install java 9. do the configurations of the java paths, and create a new project then copy the source code from the previous project to the new project.